# jQuery works in the console but not in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I wrote a snippet of jQuery to move some things around in the DOM. The code works in the console but when I put it in my `functions.php` file it does not work. Is there an easier place to put it? My code is below:

```
    function move_header_nav_items() {
  ?>
  <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            jQuery('#main-navigation').detach().insertBefore('nav.std-menu');
        }); 
  </script>
  <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'move_header_nav_items' );
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in your browser's console?

Comment: Hi,do check the browser console (press F12 on keyboard). most likely issue i could think off, is that you call jQuery before it being loaded, the order of the script tags is important.

Comment: I'd be curious whether, in the resulting page, jQuery gets loaded before or after your script. But seriously, use your console for clues.